# Не получаю данные с сервера, хотя в консоле они есть

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю даннные с фейкового сервера. Задача: положить `title` в массив `infoApi`.
Данные получаю, проверяю в консоле, пишет массив пустой, но если его раскрыть, там отображаются все элементы. Но, при этом `length = 0`
Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?

```js
const infoApi = [];

const getApi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  const result = await response.json();
  result.map((el) => {
    infoApi.push(el.title);
  });
};

getApi();

console.log(infoApi);
console.log(infoApi.length);
```

Comment: Всё прекрасно тут.  async/await. Вот только  в итоге то данные в infoApi попадают после того как она (переменная) была выведена в консоль

Comment: Простите, но не совсем понял ответ. Могли бы более подробно подсказать в чем ошибка?

Comment: Результат работы функции асинхронный. В итоге метод вызывали и забыли про него, пошли дальше по коду, вызвался консоль лог, а в это время всё ещё где-то выполняется функция которая достаёт данные. Консоль лог уже отработал, а функция ещё нет. Вот проблема. А то что в функции прописаны await не значит что консоль будет дожидаться выполнения функций. await даёт команду, что следующая строчка **внутри этой функции** будет жать результата выполнения fetch. Так что наличие async/await ничего не дало в текущей ситуации...

Comment: В зависимости от задачи ответ будет разный. В текущем виде чтобы решить задачу, надо сделать ещё одну асинхронную функцию, которая будет делать `let result = await getApi()` ......а в `getApi` делать `return infoApi` вот тогда что-то ещё получится. Тогда внутри первой асинхронной можно оперировать результатом........... либо делать `getAPi().then(...........);`

Comment: Спасибо, да теперь понял! Почему так происходит!